# SVG curved area path (M C) - don't end at start (cut)

Tags: svg, path

I have this SVG path:

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 500 500">
  <path fill="red" d="
        M 326 147
        C 329 135 345 130 355 137
        C 376 150 385 188 362 197
        C 339 206 318 170 326 147
        M 381 222
        C 418 214 408 157 385 127   
        C 370 108 340 96 326 115
        C 296 154 334 233 381 222
    ">
  </path>
  <g>
    <path fill="blue" d="M 326 151 A 4 4 0 1 1 326.00399999933336 150.99999800000018 Z"></path>
    <path fill="blue" d="M 355 141 A 4 4 0 1 1 355.00399999933336 140.99999800000018 Z"></path>
    <path fill="blue" d="M 362 203.54315907595438 A 5.999822352380809 5.999822352380809 0 1 1 362.0059998213524 203.54315607604343 Z"></path>
    <path fill="blue" d="M 326 119.76249999999999 A 4 4 0 1 1 326.00399999933336 119.76249800000015 Z"></path>
    <path fill="blue" d="M 385 132 A 4 4 0 1 1 385.00399999933336 131.99999800000018 Z"></path>
    <path fill="blue" d="M 381 228.81468927464363 A 5.9996841892833 5.9996841892833 0 1 1 381.0059996831893 228.81468627480177 Z"></path>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/coa9hd7g/

[image]

I'm trying to get SVG that starts from A1 and A2 and ends on C1 and C2 like on the image below:

[image]

Any clues on how to achieve it? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can delete the last bezier from every group, change the M command in the middle with a line L and close the path with a Z like so:

```css
svg{width:90vh}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="300 100 150 150">
  <path fill="red" d="
        M 326 147
        C 329 135 345 130 355 137
        C 376 150 385 188 362 197
        L 381 222
        C 418 214 408 157 385 127   
        C 370 108 340 96 326 115
        z
    ">
  </path>
```